# Suppress Parse.com ios notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications

I am currently using Parse.com to handle push notifications. Right now I have push notifications fire when a user submits a friend request. The notification appears when the user is either in the app or not using the app at all. This is fine. However, I now have setup push notifications for when a user gets a message from another user. I want to only show the notification if the user isn't already actively chatting (this can get annoying since it appears as an Alert box in-app).

How can I fire the following push notification if the user is not using the app?

```
let push = PFPush()
push.setQuery(pushQuery)
push.setMessage("\(self.senderDisplayName) sent you a new message!")
push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the push notification if the app is in **active state**, For that you have to comment the **handlePush** method, which is written in delegate method,

Like this,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    //PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)//This is the method, showing the alert view while receiving the notification.
}
```

The **Alternative** method will be,

- whenever your app goes to background, you have to indicate the server to send the notification.

**Update- For reading the notification**

You have to configure the notification payload to differentiate the notification based on **type**.

```
    [
    "aps" : [
        "alert" : "Title",
        "type" : "NotificationType"
    ] 
]
```

based on the key "type", you can disable the notification alert.
Hope this helps.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there a way to disable this for only certain notifications? I'd like to disable this for my new message notification, but keep the alert for the other type